# JavaScript to write a Discord bot wont work with a "forEach" function

Tags: javascript

I am working on this Discord bot, but it seems that I can't get started well. I hope you guys can help. I want the bot to give me a list of channels there is in the Discord so I can receive the channel ID from it. Here is the code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log("Connected as " + client.user.tag);

  client.user.setActivity("Playing BackSideRP");
  client.guilds.forEach((guilds) => {
    console.log(guild.name);
  });
});
```

And here is what it says at the terminal:

> (node:20572) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: client.guilds.forEach is not a function

If anyone have any suggestion on how to fix this problem, please do write back! :)

Comment: I fixed your code block.

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what the problem is: _"client.guilds.forEach is not a function"_. The `forEach` method can only be called on arrays. What the error is telling you is that `client.guilds` is not an array... which is why the method doesn't exist.

Comment: Arh thx, new to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hard time (not really, just googled a bit xD) I found a solution to my problem. Thx for the help. Here is the code for it to work:

```
client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
     console.log(guild.name)
```

Comment: ^_^ reading the docs and googling is your most powerful tool in programming

Comment: True, what a powerful tool haha >_<

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [documentation for `Client.guilds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds). It says the type is [`GuildManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager) so apparently it is not a list so you cannot use `forEach` on it.